# Cloud masking of Sentinel-2 product using SNAP

Tags: masking, sentinel-2, cloud-gis

I am using Sentinel-2 images in tropical region where almost all image contains clouds which needs to be masked out.

1. What is the best way to remove the clouds from the image in all the bands, is SNAP is the right tool?
2. After masking out the clouds how do I interpolate the empty cells of the raster?

Comment: As per the [Tour] please ask only one question per question.